# datatable : multi criteria research from input field

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable and I want to be able to search in the table from html inputs which are not related to datatable

my html :

```
<div id="general>
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="lastname"/>
<input type="text" id="birthday"/>
<table id="table-search" class="display col-sm-4">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>lastname</th>
    <th>birthday</th>
    <th>blah</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td>john</td> 
         <td>doe</td>
        <td>1970/1/1</td>
        <td>bla bla</td>
        <td>johnny</td> 
         <td>doenut</td>
        <td>1970/1/1</td>
        <td>bla bla</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

If i put `john` in `name` input + `doe` in `lastname` input, 
I want to have result :

```
  |john|doe
  |johnny|doenut
```

I manage to search in the table with `fnFilter()`, but I can't do research like :  `value1 AND value2 AND value3`. It delete the previous `valueX` result.

```
    $('.general input').keyup( function () {
    var name =  $('#name').val();
    var lastname =  $('#lastname').val();
    var birthday =  $('#birthday').val();

      oTable.fnFilter( name+lastname+birthday ); <-- i want a request like this


    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom filters to DataTables, just use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push();`, but pass it all of your filters. Makes more sense when you see it. For example:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var filterFirstName = $('#name').val();
    if(filterFirstName == '') { return true; }
    return data[0].indexOf(filterFirstName) != -1;
  },
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var filterLastName = $('#lastname').val();
    if(filterLastName == '') { return true; }
    return data[1].indexOf(filterLastName) != -1;
  }
);
```

That code would add two filters, one for first name and one for last. You can see it obtains the value of the two filter inputs first, if they aren't set to anything, it returns true (if all filters pass as true for a row it will be shown, otherwise it will be hidden). If the filter has a value, we can compare it to the value shown in the corresponding column (`data` here is an array of the data in the current row - `0` is the location of the first name column, and `1` is of the last name column). If the values don't match, it returns false (which hides the column) if they do, it returns true (again, if all filters are true the row is shown).

Then you simply have to redraw the table on `keyup` for the inputs:

```
$('#general input').keyup(function() {
    oTable.draw();
});
```

You can see this in action with your data here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7okphu3/

Comment: Thanks you very mcuch for this complete answer !  It does exactly what i want on the fiddle, but in my code i'm gettinn error : `TypeError: oTable.draw is not a function` with data table cdn 1.10.12

Comment: Working now, I just  have to figure out why it doesn't update the table after a backspace. Thank you again !!